# AvalancheImagineBundle creating simple thumbs doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, bundle

I have a problem with AvalancheImagineBundle for Symfony 2

I followed the basic instructions but it doesn't work

```
<img src="{{ ('/mywebsite/web/uploads/myphoto.jpg')| apply_filter('my_thumb')}}"/>
```

my image is here without the apply_filter but with the filter, i have this and a not found image.

```
<img src="/mywebsite/web/app_dev.php/media/cache/my_thumb/mywebsite/web/uploads/myphoto.jpg">
```

any clues ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that image path you use is wrong. It should be relative path to the image, like this - `<img src="{{ 'uploads/myphoto.jpg'| apply_filter('my_thumb')}}"/>`

Also think that it is a good idea to use [forked bundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle) instead, because it has more features and more active developers.

Comment: Thx it works:) but strange `<img src="{{ '/mywebsite/web/uploads/myphoto.jpg'}}"/>` works but with the filter, I should remove `/mywebsite/web/`

Comment: @Tib: That is because `apply_filter` normalizes path based on the value of `web_root` in `config.yml`.